# Image on back card not showing when flipped, JS memory game

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user clicks on one of playing cards in this memory game, it fires off a `flipCard` function that transforms the card along the Y axis by 180deg, essentially showing the rotating the image that is hidden on the back and making it visible in the front. My eventListener and the `flipCard` function is working but there's a problem with the CSS because the back image won't appear. Despite it only supposed to rotate 180deg, the image on the front rotates and still appears on the front after `flipCard` is invoked. Can someone take a look at my CSS and suggest how to make the back image appear?

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

function flipCard(){
    this.classList.toggle('flip');
}

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Bungee Shade', cursive;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1{
    color: black
}
h1:hover{
    color:blue;
}
.card{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    transform: scale(1); 
    transition: transform .5s;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: black;  
    border: 5px double #000000;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto; 
    perspective: 500px;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.card.flip {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card-back{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/*
.card .card-back,
.card .card-front{
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in;
}

.card-front, .card-back{
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
*/
.overlay{
    font-size: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Shade&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Memory Game</h1>

<section class="gameboard">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="card" id = "monster1">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="1" img src="monster1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster8">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="2" img src="monster8.png">
        </div>   
        <div class="card" id = "monster3">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="3" img src="monster3.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster5">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="5" img src="monster5.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="row">
        <div class="card" id = "monster6" >
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="6" img src="monster6.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster4">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="4" img src="monster4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster8">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="2" img src="monster8.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster1">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="1" img src="monster1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="card" id = "monster3">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="3" img src="monster3.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster5">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="5" img src="monster5.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster4">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="4" img src="monster4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id = "monster6">
            <img class="card-front" img src="logo.png" height="120px" width="120px">
            <img class="card-back" type="6" img src="monster6.png">
        </div>
    </div>
 
</section>

<div class="overlay">
    <h1>Great job!  </h1>
</div>  

<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```